# Curling/Shuffleboard game, making the stone move in more than 1 direction

Tags: java, simulation, physics

I'm creating a small curling/shuffleboard game in java, where I'm emphasizing on the physics.

At the moment the game can shove the curlingstone along the x-axis using the following to calculate the x position. The player can decide the initial x-velocity.

```
xPos = xIniVel* time - 0.5 * mu * mass * g * time* time;
```

I'm using a gameTimer which runs as long as the ball is in motion.

```
double speed = xIniVel- mu * G * mass * time;

if (speed <= 0.0) {gameTimer.stop();}
```

The method updateDisplay() then redraws the ball/curlingstone at the new position.

```
int x = (int) (xPos* 100);
int y = (int) (yPos* 100);
g.setColor(Color.green);
g.fillOval(x, y, 22, 22);
```

The problem I'm having is how can I make the stone anywhere else than along the x-axis? Preferably I want the player to type in an angle, but an initial y-velocity will also work.

Edit: [Screenshot of the game.](http://imgur.com/Sk9l6sw)

Answer (score 0):

By adding exactly the same code for the y velocity as you have for the x

```
yPos = yIniVel* time - 0.5 * mu * mass * g * time* time;
```

Comment: I tried that, typing 1 for x-iniVel and 0 for yIniVel, which is supposed to keep the curling stone still along the y-axis. Instead the stone does a small turn upwards.

The speed variable has to be modified aswell, with the y-initial vel in mind.

Comment: What does the 0.5 represent?

Comment: Using equation [5] on this list.

http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/4/3/6/436357594271ec28379aa9b0e6342b5a.png

Comment: He is calculating current position, so he needs to calculate the distance traveled given some time. Something like d = vt + (1/2)at^2

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to use an initial angle and velocity would be to use trigonometry to solve for the x velocity and y velocity components.

http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/vectors/u3l2d.cfm

This webpage provides a basic understanding of doing so. Then simply copy the code you used for the x position and replace the x initial velocity with the y initial velocity.

Also, your equation for motion seems somewhat flawed. Even if there is no initial velocity, you still end up with an increasing negative position. This is because xIniVel * time = 0, then 0 - (0.5*mu*mass*g*time^2) = -(0.5*mu*mass*g*time^2).

Comment: Thanks. I now use:

    xVel = iniVel * Math.cos(angle);
    yVel = iniVel * Math.sin(angle);

But as you said, the equation for motion isn't quite right. The stone moves in a curve, when it should be moving along a straight line.

Comment: Well, the only force on the curling stone is friction, so that means the net force is Mu*m*g. Since the Fnet = m*a, then a = Mu * g. So the Equation of Motion should be D=(v*t)-(0.5*(Mu*g)*t^2). It should be noted that in this case, you'd want to use the Kinetic Coefficient of Friction for Mu, which should be, if I recall correctly, zero when an object is stopped. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks again.

I started over with a different take on it. Now the user just writes an angle and start velocity. Then I use sinus and cosinus to split the speed in x and y. Then I just xPos = xPos + IniVelx * time, and  IniVelX = IniVelx * mu. Then the same for Y. Atleast it works.